# Parse multipart/form-data in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, multipartform-data

I am developing a perl program that POST data in the form of multi-part MIME to a web service. I have received the following data from the server. I used `HTTP::Request::Common` module to submit data.

How do i parse the following data in perl.

_content:

```
--AaioCdPr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AAA"

TMP
--AaioCdPr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BBB"

TEST
--AaioCdPr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BBBBCC"

TEST
--AaioCdPr
```

Comment: Do you receive the data has a CGI request? If so, the CGI module would do.

Comment: I dont think CGI can do anything here. I used the following snippet of code to POST data.

my $usrag1  = LWP::UserAgent->new();
        my ($req1,$response1);

        $req1=POST(
                    http://www.example.com/webservice,
                    Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
                    Content      => [
                                        Type    => "XXXX",
                                        Mode    => "XXXXX"
                                    ]
                );
        $response1 = $usrag1->request($req1);

Comment: Response from webservice as:- (Content of $response1)

'_rc' => '200',
                 '_headers' => bless( {
                                        'x-powered-by' => 'Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1',
                                        'XXXXXX' => 1
                                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_msg' => 'OK',
                 '_request' => bless( {
                                        '_content' => '--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AAAA"

BBBBBB
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CCCCCC"

DDDDDDDD
--xYzZY

Comment: Im able to process _content by spliting \r\n & with pattern matching. Im just looking if there exist a standard approach for this.

Comment: Re "I dont think CGI can do anything here.", I never said it did. You do not receive the data from a CGI request, so the suggestion to use CGI doesn't apply.

Comment: My apologies if I hurt you by using 'I dont think', really i mean 'i don't know'. Thanks very much for your support. I will do check MIME Parser & let you know.

Answer (score 0):

nb4: "What have you tried?"

Seems like you could pull the information you want with a regex: `(?:(\w+)\r\n)?--AaioCdPr\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="(\w+)"`

`$1` will contain your string like "TMP" or "TEST" and `$2` will contain your string like "BBB" or "BBBBCC"

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I tried regex & patten matching for this and found working. I would like to know if there is any standard approach to parse data from this form. Because I got a variable $response with full http header & content back from the server.

Comment: Respose like :  '_rc' => '200', '_headers' => bless( { 'x-powered-by' => 'Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1', 'XXXXXX' => 1 }, 'HTTP::Headers' ), '_msg' => 'OK', '_request' => bless( { '_content' => '--xYzZY Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AAAA" BBBBBB --xYzZY Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CCCCCC" DDDDDDDD --xYzZY –  IAM ABLE TO PROCESS _content, but looking for alternatives.

Comment: Haha, it's a little difficult for me to see what's going on with everything squished into a comment. If this regex does what you want, I'd recommend that you accept this answer and post a new question with the header and exactly what you are looking to extract from it. Perl is such a great language for string processing that we can probably even find a one line solution to your problem. I just need to see it clearly defined.

Answer (score 0):

I use [HTTP::MultiPartParser](https://metacpan.org/release/HTTP-MultiPartParser) for this. Maybe it's also good for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

I see "MIME parser" or similar three times in the first five [search results](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=MIME;s=1) for MIME on CPAN.